# Calling Javascript Function with Arguments in HTML document using VBA

Tags: javascript, html, excel, vba

I tried searching through the forums to find the answer to this question but I can't seem to get down a solution that works. I have a website I'm trying to access and the only way that I can navigate through it is by clicking through it and waiting for the next page to load. However, I've run one section I can't seem to activate. Below is the HTML code that I've located via Inspect Element for the button that I need to select to follow to the next page.

```
<a class="tabLinkMenu" id="ElementID";" 
onclick="selectOneItem('LinktoNextPage');fnLink('argument1','argument2','argument3');" 
href="javascript:void(0);">Inner Text</a>`
```

To access this piece of the code, I'm using the following VBA code which generates the HTML above when I debug.print.

```
Set ObjA = IE.document.getElementById("ElementID")
```

I've tried running "ObjA.Click" in VBA to go to follow the link but nothing happens. I believe this has to do with the "fnLink" located within the code but I can't seem to locate that function in the JavaScript sections nor were my attempts to call it effective.

I tried calling the function in VBA using these methods with no avail.

1. this

   ```
   IE.navigate ("javascript:fnLink('argument 1','argument 2','argument 3');")
   ```
2. and this

   ```
   IE.document.parentWindow.execScript "javascript:fnLink('argument 1','argument 2','argument 3');"
   ```

This is a secure site so I can't provide the entire HTML code.

I appreciate any advice you may have.

Thanks!

S

Comment: not sure of the scope of `ObjA`, so just a thought: what happens if you try `IE.document.getElementById("ElementID").Click`?

Comment: Oh wow! That was too easy. Thank you! I had defined ObjA as an Object based on previous experience but when I removed that reference it worked.